# Combine two dicts into a dict of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on an eCommerce system using Django.

I am storing the attributes of a product in a Postgresql JSONField.

I have created a form which has the required data.

I store `form.cleaned_data` as the value in the field.

Instead of replacing the current field value with the new one I want to combine the old and the new attributes to be added.

## case 1:

If I have 2 dicts as:

```
a = {"label": "color", "type": "spu"}
b = {"label": "size", "type": "sku"}
```

and I want to create a parent dict containing those dicts as:

```
combined = {
    {"label": "color", "type": "spu"},
    {"label": "size", "type": "sku"}
}
```

## case 2

If I have a dict of multiple dicts:

```
a = {
    {"label": "color", "type": "spu"},
    {"label": "size", "type": "sku"}
}
```

and I want to add a third dict to it as:

```
b = {"label": "storage", "type": "sku"}

combined = {
    {"label": "color", "type": "spu"},
    {"label": "size", "type": "sku"}
    {"label": "storage", "type": "sku"}
}
```

Comment: If you want to create combined dicts like that, you'll have to provide keys for each of the values. Alternatively, you could store them in a list.

Comment: your output combined is not actually a dict.. you can do [ a, b ] if you want to have a and b in single list

Comment: Or u can create a tuple like this  (a, b)
dict needs keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update a dictionary using:

```
combined.update(b)
```

But your desire output is not correct as a dictionary requires a key per item of the dictionary.

If you do not want to create a unique key per dictionary, you probably want to use a list of dictionaries.

Comment: This will no work even if OP provide keys, because values will be overwritten. Isn't it?

Comment: I just tried combined.update() and it actually replaces/overwrites the values of combined.. But thanks for the update(). didn't know about it.

Comment: @Grigoriy Yes it the keys are the same.

Comment: So i have to create keys for each dict and then update it ?

Comment: @BaselJ.Hamadeh indeed yes. If you have a unique key per dictionary this will work. As other suggested, if you do not want a key per dictionary then you probably want a list.

Comment: This worked by creating keys as you have mentioned. ill try to assign the keys as <field_SOMEVALUE> to each dict maybe. thanks for your help.

Comment: @BaselJ.Hamadeh glad it helped!